# Reading runtime parameters in VSTest based C++ tests

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines, vstest

How can I read the runtime parameters passed to C++ unit tests when it is running under vstest.console.exe or as VSTest task in Azure DevOps build pipeline?

I am trying to read the runtime parameters set in .runsettings file or passed through overrideTestrunParameters but unable to find a way to do this.

Looks like TestContext is available only for C# based tests and not available to unmanaged C++ unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to read the runtime parameters set in .runsettings file

In Azure Devops, you could directly use the **PowerShell task** to read the runtime parameters in .runsettings file:

Here is an example:

test.runsettings

```
  <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
    <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />
    <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />
  </TestRunParameters>
```

Pipeline PowerShell task InLine Script:

```
[xml]$DSConfig = gc "$(build.sourcesdirectory)/test.runsettings" #file path

# Select <parameters> nodes
$ParametersNode = $DSConfig.SelectNodes('//Parameter')


foreach($Node in $ParametersNode)
{
   echo  Name: $Node.name Value: $Node.value
  
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I would like to read this from the test, in order to alter the test behavior, e.g., use mock interface. I will try to use PS task and pass the values as environment variables. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to use ps task to set variables, you could refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

Comment: If you need to get the value in overrideTestrunParameters, you could use the powershell to run the following rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it as answer .Thanks.